# Change key names and add values of same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's suppose that I have a dictionary like that:

```
input_dict = {'3': 2, '5': 4, '36': 7,'62':6}
```

and I want to have that as an output:

```
input_dict = {'3': 9, '5': 4, '6':6}
```

Basically, I want to do the following things:

1. Keep only the first character of the keys
2. If after that some keys are the same then add their values

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, did any of the answers helped you?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, yes (almost) all of them, lol. Shall I upvote all of them?

Comment: I believe that is a good gesture from your side, if the answer addressed your question, since every person dedicated some time to it, and you should validate the one that you think was the most useful.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and slice the `key` strings keeping only the first character:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in input_dict.items():
    d[k[0]] += v
```

---

```
print(d)
# defaultdict(int, {'3': 9, '5': 4, '6': 6})
```

Comment: i deleted my answer since we had the same idea even though mine came first (just)

Comment: Yes @chris kept mine since it was only a few secs difference which hopefully excuses having kept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
new_dict = {}
for key, val in input_dict.items():
    if key[0] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[key[0]] = val
    else:
        new_dict[key[0]] += val
```

**Output**

```py
{'3': 9, '5': 4, '6': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method from a dictionary:

```
input_dict = {'3': 2, '5': 4, '36': 7, '62': 6}

result = {}
for k, v in input_dict.items():
    key = k[0]
    result[key] = v + result.get(key, 0)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'3': 9, '5': 4, '6': 6}
```